# Se puede crear un modelo de una table intermedia de una relacion muchos a muchos?

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent, relaciones, modelorelacional

tengo dos tablas llamadas productos y cliente, cada una con su respectivo modelo en eloquent y quiero implementar una tabla para los precios personalizados para cada cliente, para esto pensaba una relacion muchos a muchos entre las dos tablas lo cual crearia una tabla intermedia llamada precios, pero me surge la duda si puedo crearle un modelo y solo relacionar cada tabla de uno a muchos con la de precios y no utilizar en si la relacion muchos a muchos de eloquent.

Comment: claro que se puede, no veo ningun impedimento para hacerlo

Comment: Cada tabla de la BD puede ser representada como un modelo en laravel y usarse como tal, he tenido algunos casos especificos en los que se necesita tener este modelo, sin embargo aunque esta sea un modelo aparte, es bueno tener la relacion muchos a muchos tal como la indica laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leyendo en la documentación de Laravel encontre que uno puede crear un modelo de la tabla pivot ( tabla intermedia ), solo que este hereda de otra clase llamada Pivot

```
class Precio extends Pivot
{
    /**
    * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
    *
    * @var bool
    */
    public $incrementing = true;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'precios';

    protected $fillable = ['id_cliente', 'id_producto', 'precio'];
}
```

y en el modelo donde se especifica la relación muchos a muchos incluir el metodo using('Modelo') especificando la clase del modelo que se creó.

```
/**
* The prices that belong to the client.
*/
public function precios()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Producto', 'precios', 'id_cliente', 'id_producto')->using('App\Models\Precio')->withPivot('precio', 'id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

esta fue la info que encontre:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models